# How to install python django rest framework on fedora 21 with yum?

Tags: django-rest-framework, fedora, fedora-21

I found that there should be package for Django's rest framework on fedora, https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/python-django-rest-framework/.

But it doesn't seem to exist when I try to install it on a fedora 21 box:

```
$ sudo yum install python-django-rest-framework
No package python-django-rest-framework available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

How do I best install Django restframework on a fedora 21 box? I don't want to use pip.

Comment: Pip is the standard way of installing Python packages, not all packages are available in the repositories. Also, that package only appears to be available in Fedora 22.

Answer (score -1):

`sudo yum install python-django` source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-django-web-framework-on-centos-7

Comment: I was not asking how to install Django, but Rest Framework, a plugin to Django. It should be quite clear if you read the question subject or body.